# Why does the index of my array change when I click on another button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist

I'm sitting on a game right now and I don't know what to do. In a nutshell, I have a player who can move towards a phone in a 3D environment. Once there, clicking on the phone opens a dialog box with different answer options. Depending on which answer I press (button) another dialog is displayed. I do this with the help of indexes.
The problem now is that the whole thing works with the first button (answerButton[1]), but as soon as I click on the second button (answerButton[2]) and the index should be e.g. 17, the program changes the index automatically to 16. So always one number lower than I actually entered in the inspector. Can anyone help me with this or give me some food for thought. I just do not understand it. Thank you.
**
Here is my code from my DialogManager:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class NPCDialouge : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DialogManager> dialouges = new List<DialogManager>();

    public bool isDialogActive = false;

    public int currentDialogIndex = 0;

    public PhoneController phoneController;

    public GameObject dialogCanvas;
    public TMP_Text questionText;
    public Button[] answerButtons;

    public int AuflegenIndex = 0;


    private int GetRandomDialogIndex()
    {
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(1, 7); // Wähle eine zufällige Zahl von 1 bis 6 aus
        return randomIndex;
    }

    public void StartRandomDialog()
    {
        if (!isDialogActive)
        {
            int randomIndex = GetRandomDialogIndex();
            currentDialogIndex = randomIndex;

            DisplayDialog(dialouges[randomIndex]);

            isDialogActive = true;
        }
    }

    public void DisplayDialog(DialogManager dialog)
    {
        dialogCanvas.SetActive(true);
        questionText.text = dialog.question;

        for(int i = 0; i < answerButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i < dialog.answers.Length)
            {
                answerButtons[i].gameObject.SetActive(true);
                answerButtons[i].GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = dialog.answers[i].answer;
            }
            else
            {
                answerButtons[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnAnswerButtonClicked(int answerIndex)
    {
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        /*---------------------------AUFLEGEN IST AUF INDEX 0!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!------------------------------------*/
        /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if(currentDialogIndex >= 0 && currentDialogIndex < dialouges.Count)
        {
            if (answerIndex >= 0 && answerIndex < dialouges[currentDialogIndex].answers.Length)
            {
                int nextDialogIndex = dialouges[currentDialogIndex].answers[answerIndex].nextDialogIndex;
                DisplayDialog(dialouges[nextDialogIndex]);
                Debug.Log("NextDialogIndex = " + nextDialogIndex);
                currentDialogIndex = nextDialogIndex;
                
                if (currentDialogIndex == AuflegenIndex)
                {
                    phoneController.Auflegen();
                }
            }
        }       
        phoneController.StopRinging();
    }

}

[System.Serializable]
public class NextDialog
{
    public string answer;
    public int nextDialogIndex;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class DialogManager

{
    public string question;
    public NextDialog[] answers;
}
```

I have tried both assigning the buttons manually and changing the order. Nothing has changed.

Comment: What are you adding to the "dialouges" collection?

Comment: The questions (dialogtext) and answers (buttontext).

Comment: What are the questions, answers, and indices? If it's too much content to post, then you should contrive a smaller set of inputs that exhibits the incorrect behavior.

Comment: I just found the problem and i am feeling so dump haha. Forgot to give the Buttons the right indexes in the inspector. All had the Index 0...